# Проблемы с импортом в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Я пытаюсь вызвать функцию "cryptPassword" из модуля "passport" и использовать её в хуке для модели "Users" (я использую sequelize).

> Экспорт функции "cryptPassword"

```
module.exports = {
    cryptPassword(password) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
                    if (err) return reject(err);
                    return resolve(hash);
                });
            });
        });
   }
};
```

> Использование функции "cryptPassword"

```
const cryptPassword = require('../config/passport').cryptPassword;
...
User.beforeCreate( (user, options) => {
    return cryptPassword(user.password)
        .then(success => user.password = success)
        .catch(err => if (err) console.log(err));
});
```

> Суть проблемы

Раньше это работало, но сегодня NodeJS выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: cryptPassword is not a function
at Function.User.beforeCreate (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\server\models\user.js:67:12)
at Promise.each.hook (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\hooks.js:130:35)
at tryCatcher (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
at Object.gotValue (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
at Object.gotAccum (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
at Object.tryCatcher (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:606:10)
at Async._drainQueue (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
at Async._drainQueues (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\iT\code\Web\projects\wcc-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)enter code here
```

> Моя попытка решить проблему

Если испорт функции "cryptPassword" перенести в хук "beforeCreate" прямо перед "return", то всё работает как и должно. Но это какой-то костыль. Как исправить это ?. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: 99%, что у вас где-то циклическая зависимость.

Comment: Вот примерно так всё ломается https://coderwall.com/p/myzvmg/circular-dependencies-in-node-js

Answer (score -1):

Вот так попробуйте Экспорт функции "cryptPassword"

```
module.exports.cryptPassword = (password)=> {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                return resolve(hash);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Или же если вы хотите импортировать как обет то  сделайте правку в строке

```
cryptPassword(password) {
```

должно быть

```
cryptPassword: function(password) {
```

или более современный вариант данной строки

```
cryptPassword:(password)=> {
```